# What Are The Practical Applications Of Perfect Numbers?

Tags: applications, perfect-numbers

What are the practical applications of perfect numbers? When googling, all I found was practical applications of mersenne primes. If you can't find any (like I), are there any applications of abundant and deficient numbers?

I understand this was asked here: [Applications of Perfect Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701037/applications-of-perfect-numbers?rq=1), but the answers only mention mersenne primes.

Comment: Create one man!

Comment: I object to the idea that things like perfect numbers need practical applications to be studied or important.  Historically, perfect numbers were hugely important for almost religious reasons e.g. by the pythagoreans.  As for the duplicate answer and your complaint that those answers only mention Mersenne primes, you should know that (*even*) perfect numbers and Mersenne primes are two sides of the same coin.  Knowledge of one facilitates knowledge of the other.  Further, the second answer there does not even make mention of Mersenne primes and only refers to perfect numbers.

Comment: I don't think that perfect numbers _need_ practical uses to be interesting, I just want to know if there are any. I don't really care about what they used to be used for, I would like a direct application just because it's fun.